# Azure Continuous Deployment - Azure SDK Version Requirement

Tags: azure, azure-devops, continuous-deployment, azure-cloud-services

When setting up **Azure Continuous Deployment** ([*`AzureContinuousDeployment.11.xaml`*](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/bharry/archive/2012/06/07/announcing-continuous-deployment-to-azure-with-team-foundation-service.aspx)) build template with our own hosted **TFS 2012 Build Controller** - it seems that the workflow activity is bound to a specific version of [`WindowsAzure.StorageClient`](https://www.nuget.org/packages/WindowsAzure.Storage). Any idea why we are getting this Compilation Exception even though we have the Azure SDK 2.4 installed on the build controller?

#### WF Activity: Deploy application to Azure - Compilation Error

> Exception Message: Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.WindowsAzure.StorageClient, Version=1.7.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified. (type FileNotFoundException)
>   Exception Stack Trace:    at System.Activities.Statements.Throw.Execute(CodeActivityContext context)
>      at System.Activities.CodeActivity.InternalExecute(ActivityInstance instance, ActivityExecutor executor, BookmarkManager bookmarkManager)
>      at System.Activities.Runtime.ActivityExecutor.ExecuteActivityWorkItem.ExecuteBody(ActivityExecutor executor, BookmarkManager bookmarkManager, Location resultLocation)

Our VSO project uses **Azure SDK 2.4**, but this is separate from the portion that uploads the CSPACK publish file (`.csx`) to the **Azure Blob Storage** for the **Azure Cloud App**.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The build template activity [**DeployAzureCloudApp**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.teamfoundation.deployment.workflow.activities.deployazurecloudapp.aspx) from `Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Deployment.Worflow.dll` references `Microsoft.WindowsAzure.StorageClient.dll 1.7.0.0`.

To work around this - we must [copy the assembly to the TFS Build Controller folder](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/cd00b397-4970-4d33-bf55-3cbde2d3e792/error-with-azure-deploy-on-self-hosted-build-controller?forum=TFService&prof=required) on the server (*where the TFSBuildServiceHost.exe resides*). Another option would be to GAC the assembly.

#### Source: *Microsoft.WindowsAzure.StorageClient.dll*

> **Azure SDK Path:** c:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Azure.NET SDK\v2.5\bin

#### Target: *Microsoft.WindowsAzure.StorageClient.dll*

> **TFS 2012 Path**: c:\Program Files\Microsoft Team Foundation Server 11.0\Tools
> **TFS 2013 Path**: c:\Program Files\Microsoft Team Foundation Server 12.0\Tools

Evidently the assembly resolution isn't looking for it outside the `Tools` directory - it seems to be specifying an absolute path to locate it. Fusion assembly log never shows it probing for this assembly.

#### Powershell to Reproduce the `FileNotFoundException` Error

```cs
([System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadFrom("Microsoft.WindowsAzure.StorageClient, Version=1.7.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35l")).FullName
```